# How do I test Ember.js routes

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js

I want to write a test for my ember.js application that looks something like this but I'm having not having any luck after Googling:

```
... setup fixtures here ...

App.navigate_to_path('/some_resource')
equal($('#some-element').text(), 'expected value', 'message')
```

Is this possible or am I approaching this from the wrong direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a function like this:

```
function navigateTo(url) {
  App.__container_.lookup('router:main').handleURL(url);
}
```

You can check out how the ember core team are testing routes [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember/tests/routing/basic_test.js)

Comment: Nice link to how ember tests routes